# scope variable inside directive is not updating - angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple directive for a table with pagination. The Pagination has   a dropdown & a button. User can either select a page in the dropdown or click on the button to navigate.
Say, the dropdown lists page numbers 1, 2, 3 and the selected page is 1. When user clicks on 'Next', the selected value in the dropdown should become 2.

**Issue:**
When Next is clicked, though the scope variable `SelectedPage` is seen updated in the console, it is not reflecting in the view.

**report.html:**

```
<div>
<ul>       
   <li>
     <select ng-model="$scope.state.SelectedPage" ng-change="ShowPageResult()">
      <option ng-repeat="num in PageNumbers value="{{num}}">{{num}}</option>
     </select>
   </li>
   <li ng-click="ShowNextPage();"><a href=" #">Next</a></li>       
</ul>
<table>
...//some html
</table>
</div>
```

**directive**

```
app.directive('Report', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',            
        replace: 'true',
        templateUrl: '/views/report.html'            
    };
});
```

**controller:**

```
$scope.state={};
$scope.ShowPageResult = function () {
        GetReport($scope.state.SelectedPage);
    }
$scope.ShowNextPage = function () {
        $scope.state.SelectedPage = $scope.state.SelectedPage + 1;                
        GetReport($scope.state.SelectedPage);
    }

//get report data to bind to table
function GetReport(pageNumber) {
        $scope.UserReport = [];

        var promise = ReportsFactory.GetData();
        promise.then(function (success) {
            if (success.data != null && success.data != '') {                
                $scope.UserReport = success.data;                
                BindPageNumbers($scope.UserReport[0].TotalRows, pageNumber);              
            }            
        },
        function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

  //bind page numbers to dropdown in pagination
    function BindPageNumbers(totalRows, selectedPage) {        
        $scope.PageNumbers = [];
        $scope.LastPageNumber = Math.ceil((totalRows / 10));
        for (var i = 1; i <= Math.ceil((totalRows / 10)) ; i++) {
            $scope.PageNumbers.push(i);
        }
        $scope.state.SelectedPage = selectedPage; //can see the no. becomes 2 here.            
    }
```

Comment: Where is the report directive being used?

Comment: In the aspx page `<report></report>`

Comment: There is no controller definition for the directive? It doesn't make sense how in the report directive template you're calling functions that don't belong to itself.

Comment: Have you tried using `transclude: true` in the directive? Since you have a `scope` parameter in your directive, a new scope is created for the directive while you want to access the `parent's` directive

Comment: @User234.. When I click on Next, I do get the data from database for the next page and it is displayed in the report. Only the page in the dropdown isnt updated.

Comment: No idea about it. how to go about it. If I remove the scope parameter in the directive, will it be any easy. I just want to access the functions in the controller and update the variables value

Answer (score 1):

My guess:

`ng-change="ShowPageResult()"` is declared in the directive template and because your directive declares its own scope, then it looks for the definition of ShowPageResult() in the directive's scope and not in the controller.

Therefore the change handler function is null and does nothing.

Comment: I also have `ShowPageResult()' in the controller. Will that help

Comment: You have 2 different scopes. Either change the directive to not declare its own scope and use the parent's or change your `SelectedPage` value to be the one in the directive's scope

Comment: I have removed the scope from directive. Still doesnt work. Any more changes I have to do in the controller?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting `SelectedPage` in an object. So in your controller

```
$scope.state = {
    SelectedPage: 1
};
```

You need to initialise the `SelectedPage`.

Then reference `SelectedPage` with `state.SelectedPage` in your controller and in your directive template:

```
<select ng-model="state.SelectedPage" ng-change="ShowPageResult()">
```

Because of javascript prototypical inheritance, the `SelectedPage` in your directive will be different to the one in your controller. See [Understanding Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#javascript-prototypal-inheritance)

And it's not clear to me why you're binding `BindPageNumbers` to your directive scope. Firstly, there is no controller in your directive so it never gets called there and there is no call in the template either.
Second, `BindPageNumbers` is not bound to the parent scope so the directive wont get that function anyway.

Comment: There is no scope parameter in the directive now. I have updated my question after putting state. The error says state is not defined at BindPageNumbers()

Comment: You should be using `$scope.state.SelectedPage` in your controller

Comment: are you calling `$scope.$apply` somewhere?

Comment: Plz ignore the error thing. Fixed that. But issue remains about the dropdown value

Comment: Will it be easier if I used a dedicated controller for the directive ? If yes, could you plz help with a lil code how that should go..

Comment: See [working plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/flzUfdX0n6xIp8Jyx51X?p=preview)

You need to initialise the `SelectedPage` of the state and in the template, you do NOT reference `$scope`. Also, I'm assuming you have a typo in your ng-repeat code. Should be `<option ng-repeat="num in PageNumbers" value="{{num}}">{{num}}</option>`

Comment: But yes, would be better in a directive. I don't see a point in this case of defining a directive and using functions from the parent controller cause it's not re-usable.